# How to deal with very high number of target vocab for sequential type model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, seq2seq

I'm currently dealing with a language model i.e sequential model and my target vocabulary to predict is really really high.

```
x = Dense(80000000, activation='softmax')
```

I can't calculate the softmax over all the vocabulary so instead I used `tf.nn.sampled_softmax` for training the model, but for evaluation on validation we still have to calculate softmax won't we? But I can't do that, it's throwing error that it doesn't fit on gpu memory when trying to do it in tensorflow

I used batch size of 32. What are the options that I have in that case? How do deal with the issue? Please help me out

Comment: In sequential it is best to use characters as target,for examples each character with maximum probs will be fed into the model to generate predict next character with maximum probs and so on

Comment: But I can't use characters as targets it's actually an sequential entity|categorical type of problem and I have to use words.

Comment: your data have `80000000` unique categories label,I think you may have mistaken,what is your dataset?

Comment: No I'm positive and I have those many target vocab to predict. It's a very huge private data-set.

Comment: when you say `vocal` you mean words right? if yes, then it is the case of character level model

Comment: I just meant that there are those many words (i.e categories | entities) to predict from. So that would become my target vocabulary. That's what I meant. I can't use a character level model because those are named entities not language model.